# how can I sort rows by different criteria, with postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have the following:

```
    id              int         GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    ts              timestamp   WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
    urgent          bool        NOT NULL,
    origin          varchar     NOT NULL,
    message         varchar     NOT NULL,
    ts_read         timestamp   WITHOUT TIME ZONE

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_alerts ON {accountId}.{tableAlertsName} (ts_read) WHERE ts_read IS NULL;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW {accountId}.pending_alerts AS
    SELECT id, ts, level, origin, message from {accountId}.{tableAlertsName}
    WHERE ts_read IS NULL ORDER BY urgent DESC, ts ASC;"
```

And I would like to replace the *urgent* column with a *level* column that would have a few options such as *info*, *warning*, *error*, etc.

But in my view, I would like to achieve the following sort operation:

If level = warning or level = error then add these first, if not, then sort the rest by timestamp.

How can I implement this kind of sort operation?

Comment: Be aware that the order by clause in the view does not guarantee the same order will be used for the results in a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are warning and error supposed to be tied with each other, or separated?  If they are tied:

```
ORDER BY (level = 'warning' or level = 'error') DESC, ts ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use a union all for the view and first query will be for where clause on levels and second query will be on order by  for timestamp.

   CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW {accountId}.pending_alerts AS
   SELECT id, ts, level, origin, message
   from {accountId}.{tableAlertsName}
   WHERE (ts_read IS NULL AND (level = warning or level = error))
   UNION ALL
   (SELECT id, ts, level, origin, message from {accountId}.{tableAlertsName}
   WHERE ts_read IS NULL ORDER BY urgent DESC, ts ASC)
2. View can be costly for performance, you can use a function to create similar scenario.

   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pending_alerts ()
   RETURNS TABLE(id int, .....)
   AS $$
   BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT id, ts, level, origin, message from {accountId}.{tableAlertsName}
   WHERE (ts_read IS NULL AND (level = warning or level = error))
   UNION ALL
   (SELECT id, ts, level, origin, message from {accountId}.{tableAlertsName}
   WHERE ts_read IS NULL ORDER BY urgent DESC, ts ASC);
   END;
   $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;